# How to pass variable in C++ Sprintf 2nd(format) argument?

Tags: c++

I've been cracking heads on how to achieve this in C++:

```
string format = "what is your %s";  
new_string = sprintf(buffer, format, name);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `format.c_str()`:

```
string format = "what is your %s";  
int total = sprintf(buffer, format.c_str(), name);
```

Also note the returned value is not the new string, it is the *buffer* which is the output string. The returned value is actually the total number of characters written. This count does not include the additional null-character automatically appended at the end of the string. On failure, a negative number is returned ([see doc here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)).

But in C++, `std::ostringstream` is better and typesafe, as @Joachim explained in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "what is your " << name;
std::string new_string = os.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always do something like:

```
char buffer[100]; 
string format = "what is your %s";
sprintf(buffer, format.c_str(), name.c_str());
string new_string(buffer);
```

Alternatively, use a `stringstream`:

```
stringstream buf;
buf << "what is your " << name;
string new_string = buf.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

The format passed to `sprintf` must be a `char*`, not a `std::string`.
`sprintf` also returns the number of characters written, not a pointer to the constructed buffer.

```
int len = sprintf(buffer, "what is your%s", name);
std::string new_string(buffer, len);
```

Another possibility would be to use `std::ostringstream` to perform your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem here - `sprintf` is a function that takes in a `char*` as its first argument, and a `const char*` as its second. These are both C data types, and so I don't know if using a C++ string will be recognised by the compiler as valid.

Also, the function returns an int (the number of characters written), not a string, which it looks like you're expecting with a return value like `new_string`.

For more information, you can look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/

Answer (score -1):

You may use `stringstream` form the C++ STL which is more OO.

Check out the [documentation](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

`sprintf` is part of the C library, and thus don't know anything about std::string. Use char* instead if you still want to use it.

To get the C `char*` string from an `std::string`, uses [c_str](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method.